# How can I conditionally insert a character into a string?

Tags: python, string

Brand new to programming, what I've learned so far I've just copied from similar examples online.

This is a random sentence generator for a foreign language. But, I want to insert a character in between two specific characters in a string if they happen to occur next to each other. In this case, I want the characters in the evowel and avowel variables to be separated by 'y'.

I thought I could try a conditional split + rejoin, but I'm not sure how to search for (in this case) evowel_avowel, split it at that boundary, insert y, then join it back. So a randomly generated string 'eametetuk' would change to 'eyametetuk', 'eseapah' > 'eseyapah' etc.

Edit: I need to be able to handle anything in the evowel with anything in the avowel. For simplicity's sake I've only included two varations of each, but the language has more vowels and more variations (so roughly 60 permutations where this change needs to happen).

Would I need to create my own function for this? I'm guessing I would need regex somewhere.

```py
import random

c1 = ("e","é")
c2 = ("a","se")
root = ("apa","mete")
tense = ("h","tuk")

avowel = ("a","á")
evowel = ("e","é")

#syntax
x = [c1,c2,root,tense]

#randomly selects morphemes
s = "".join([random.choice(i) for i in x])

print(s)
```

Comment: What about `<string_name>.replace('ea', 'eya')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a replacement like below.

```
import random

c1 = ("e","é")
c2 = ("a","se")
root = ("apa","mete")
tense = ("h","tuk")

avowel = "éá"
avowelr= "éyá"
evowel = "ea"
evowelr = "eya"

#syntax
x = [c1,c2,root,tense]

#randomly selects morphemes
s = "".join([random.choice(i) for i in x])
s = s.replace(avowel, avowelr)
s = s.replace(evowel, evowelr)
print(s)
```

Comment: That only covers cases with "éá" and "ea" though, I need to be able to cover any possible combination of E's and A's (there are more vowels in the language where this will happen, I just used two here for simplicity). I definitely can do it like that, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution than just manually writing out all possible vowel combinations which need to be handled

Comment: Can you please add that to your description?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression (`re` module):

```
import re
txt1 = "eametetuk"
txt2 = "eseapah"
evowel = ("e","é")
avowel = ("a","á")
evowels = "|".join(evowel)
avowels = "|".join(avowel)
out1 = re.sub(r'('+evowels+')('+avowels+')',r'\1y\2',txt1)
out2 = re.sub(r'('+evowels+')('+avowels+')',r'\1y\2',txt2)
print(out1) # eyametetuk
print(out2) # eseyapah
```

That method will work for any evowel-avowel combination, for example:

```
txt3 = "xéay"
out3 = re.sub(r'('+evowels+')('+avowels+')',r'\1y\2',txt3)
print(out3) # xéyay
```

and so on.

Explanation: I used `|` which inside regular expression pattern mean LOGICAL OR. Then I created pattern with two groups - denoted by brackets, then in second argument of `re.sub` I write that I want 1stgroup then letter y then 2nd group.

Note that `re.sub`'s group indexing start at 1 rather than 0, also note that I used raw strings, meaning I do not have to escape `\` in order to point 1st group and 2nd group.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by iterating through all pairs of characters in your string, checking if the first is in evowels and the second in avowels, returning the first with following `y` if yes, otherwise the first only.
If this is done in a list comprehension it can be directly joined to the resulting string:

```
txt1 = "eametetuk"
txt2 = "eseapah"
evowel = 'eé' #("e","é")    you're free to put all vowels in one string, too'
avowel = 'aá' #("a","á")    because strings are also iterables

def vowel_pair_sep(txt, sep='y', ev='eé', av='aá'):
    return (''.join(
    e + sep
    if (e in ev) and (a in av)
    else e
    for e, a in zip(txt[:-1], txt[1:]))
    + txt[-1])

vowel_pair_sep(txt1)
# eyametetuk
vowel_pair_sep(txt2)
# eseyapah
```

Because the separator and the vowels are parameters of the function, it can easily be adapted to different needs:

```
vowel_pair_sep('tkdgtkdg', '_', 'dt', 'gk')
# t_kd_gt_kd_g
```